# How do the vehicle respawn mechanics work in DayZ?

Tags: dayz-2012

Basically, I'm soaking wet for the helicopter. I've practiced a ton, and I'm ready to fly it live.

However, how do the spawn mechanics work?

I ask this for vehicles in general.

Comment: Also, heli's have been disabled for the time being. This has been for the last few weeks as they needed to work out some bugs with it I suppose. So don't spend too much time server hopping to find one, because for now you never will until a patch states that they have added them back.

Answer (score 2):

The only information I could find on the subject is the [DayZ Wiki Vehciles page](http://dayzwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Vehicles) where it states

> Will my vehicle stay where I left it?
>
> - You have to Save the vehicle in order for it to stay where you left it.
> - Other people can take or destroy the vehicle if they want.
> - **If a vehicle is unused, bugged or left, it will respawn after a minimum of 7 days.**

(emphasis mine).

As I understand it a vehicle spawn point will **never** spawn a new vehicle as long as the existing vehicle is in use and has not been destroyed.  If the vehicle is destroyed or left unused for 7 days then I believe that the vehicle will respawn after the next server restart.

I'm not sure where the vehicle will respawn though - I have heard that vehicles can also spawn either at their original location or at the point where it was last saved, repaired or even where it was destroyed.  If this is the case then it implies that vehicles are probably never going to be found at their original spawn point.

Comment: I'm certain that vehicles that have been left / bugged / destroyed will respawn at one of the pre defined spawnpoints for that vehicle. Source: Experience